# Oracle sql - Adding sql row value from one table as column value count to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, create-table

I have the following tables and values in my schema

```
CREATE TABLE products
(product_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 product_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE packages
(package_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 package_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT package_pk PRIMARY KEY (package_id)
);

CREATE TABLE product_packages
(product_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 package_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id),
 CONSTRAINT package_fk FOREIGN KEY (package_id) REFERENCES packages(package_id)
);

CREATE TABLE customers
(customer_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 customer_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(order_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 customer_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 product_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 quantity NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT ord_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id),
 CONSTRAINT ord_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
);


INSERT  INTO products (product_id, product_name) VALUES (1, 'BARBB');
INSERT  INTO products (product_id, product_name) VALUES (2, 'BARHB');
INSERT  INTO products (product_id, product_name) VALUES (3, 'BARFB');
INSERT  INTO packages (package_id, package_name) VALUES (1, 'BRF');
INSERT  INTO packages (package_id, package_name) VALUES (2, 'LNC');
INSERT  INTO packages (package_id, package_name) VALUES (3, 'DNR');
INSERT  INTO product_packages (product_id, package_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT  INTO product_packages (product_id, package_id) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT  INTO product_packages (product_id, package_id) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT  INTO product_packages (product_id, package_id) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT  INTO product_packages (product_id, package_id) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT  INTO product_packages (product_id, package_id) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT  INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name) VALUES (1, 'John Smith');
INSERT  INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name) VALUES (2, 'Adam Nash');
INSERT  INTO orders (order_id, customer_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 1);
INSERT  INTO orders (order_id, customer_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (2, 2, 3, 2);
```

What I want to do is to add columns to the ORDER table with package names in PACKAGES table; if that product contains the corresponding package, then indicate QUANTITY column value, otherwise 0; the result should look like

```
ORDER_ID    CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_ID  QUANTITY    BRF  LNC    DNR
--------    ----------- ----------  --------    ---  ---    ---
1           1           2           1           1    0      1
2           2           3           2           2    2      2
```

--UPDATE: NEW QUESTION
And can I do multiple pivots on one table; like I modify my ORDERS table to

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(order_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 customer_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 product_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 adl_q NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 kid_q NUMBER(5),
 CONSTRAINT ord_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id),
 CONSTRAINT ord_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
);
```

and when kid_qty is not zero that means the new corresponding package names will be created and can do pivot on them as well; for the ORDER table like

```
INSERT  INTO orders (order_id, customer_id, product_id, adl_qty, kid_qty) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT  INTO orders (order_id, customer_id, product_id, adl_qty, kid_qty) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 2, 1);
```

you should get the result:

```
ORDER_ID  CUSTOMER_ID  PRODUCT_ID  ADL_Q  KD_Q  BRF LNC  DNR  KDBRF KDLNC KDDNR
--------  ----------- ----------  ------ ----  ---  ---  ---  -----  ----  ----
       1            1          1       1    1    1    0    1     1     0      0
       2            2          2       2    2    1    2    2     1     0      2
```

Answer (score 1):

This `pivot` query worked for me:

**<sup>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f84d9/1)</sup>**

```
select order_id, customer_id, product_id, 
       nvl(brf, 0) brf, nvl(lnc, 0) lnc, nvl(dnr, 0) dnr
  from orders 
  left join (
    select product_id, package_name 
      from product_packages 
      join packages using (package_id))
    using (product_id) 
  pivot (max(quantity) for package_name in ('BRF' brf, 'LNC' lnc, 'DNR' dnr))
  order by order_id
```

Result:

```
ORDER_ID CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_ID        BRF        LNC        DNR
-------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       1           1          2          1          0          1
       2           2          3          2          2          2
```

Comment: this is nice, but can I do multiple pivots on one table as in updated question above

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation (as well as `pivot`):

```
select o.order_id, o.customer_id, o.product_id, 
       sum(case when p.package_name = 'BRF' then o.quantity else 0 end) as brf,
       sum(case when p.package_name = 'LNC' then o.quantity else 0 end) as lnc,
       sum(case when p.package_name = 'DNR' then o.quantity else 0 end) as dnr
from orders o left join
     product_packages pp
     on o.product_id = pp.product_id left join
     packages p
     on pp.package_id = p.package_id
group by o.order_id, o.customer_id, o.product_id
order by o.order_id;
```